# Symbolic manipulation softwares that can work with sums

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

I am wondering if there is any CAS that can work with formal sums and formal products.

For example, say is there any software that can comprehend expressions like

$\sum_{n=1}^k (x-n)^2$ or $\prod_{n=1}^k(x-n)$

as an expression in terms of $x,n$ and take derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: Mathematica does both. For basic summations and products, Wolfram-Alpha will do them. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%28x-k%29%5E2%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Product%5B%28x-k%29%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D)

Comment: I should add that taking the derivative is not hard either: [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5BSum%5B%28x-k%29%5E2%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D%2Cx%5D) and [2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5BProduct%5B%28x-k%29%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D%2Cx%5D)

Comment: Oh wow! That's exactly what I was hoping for!